# Return a table's row from a stored procedure in a Logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic app, triggered by a HTTP post, that runs a MSSQL stored procedure (using `Execute stored procedure (V2)`).

The procedure returns the following:

```
{
  "ResultSets": {
    "Table1": [
      {
        "DriverSerialNo": 167,
        ...
        "DateCreated": "2023-02-02T14:51:18.94"
      }
    ]
  },
  "OutputParameters": {}
}
```

I'd like to return the content of `ResultSets.Table1[0]` as the app's response, but I'm having difficultly doing so.

Should I be using a `Response` action?  How do I get the `Body` attribute to be `ResultSets.Table1[0]`?  Maybe a `Filter array` action?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use an expression for the `body`:

```
"Response": {
    "inputs": {
        "body": "@body('Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)')?['resultsets']['table1']",
        "statusCode": 200
    },
    "kind": "Http",
    "runAfter": {
        "Execute_stored_procedure_(V2)": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "type": "Response"
}
```